# Docker installation on Ubuntu 20.04 fails

Tags: docker

I'm trying to install Docker on Ubuntu 20.04

I started with documentation from the developer, got problem on 4th step

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет docker-ce недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «docker-ce» не найден кандидат на установку
E: Невозможно найти пакет docker-ce-cli
E: Невозможно найти пакет containerd.io
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «containerd.io»
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью регулярного выражения «containerd.io
```

Then I tried other instruction:

> At first upgrade package lists:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> Then install packages to allow APT to function using HTTPS:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
> ```
>
> Add GPG key for official Docker repository to your system:
>
> ```
> curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Add Docker repository to APT sources:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
> ```
>
> Then update package database:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> Make sure that installation will run using Docker repository:
>
> ```
> apt-cache policy docker-ce
> ```
>
> You should get output like shown below (while Docker version may vary):
> Output of `apt-cache policy docker-ce`
>
> ```
> docker-ce:
>  Installed: (none)
>  Candidate: 5:19.03.9~3-0~ubuntu-focal
>  Version table:
>     5:19.03.9~3-0~ubuntu-focal 500
>        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
> ```
>
> Please note that `docker-ce` package is not installed, but acts as package installation candidate of Docker for Ubuntu 20.04 (focal version).
>
> Install Docker:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install docker-ce
> ```

While following the guide above it stopped again with:

```
Распаковывается docker-ce-cli (5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) …
dpkg-deb (подпроцесс): разжимающий элемент архива: ошибка lzma: сжатые данные по
вреждены
dpkg-deb: ошибка: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-i7eupn/2-docker-ce-cli_5
%3a20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 не удалось скопировать извлечённые данные «./usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/doc
ker-buildx» в «/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx.dpkg-new»: неожидан
ный конец файла или потока
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета docker-ce.
Подготовка к распаковке …/3-docker-ce_5%3a20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается docker-ce (5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета docker-ce-rootless-extras.
Подготовка к распаковке …/4-docker-ce-rootless-extras_5%3a20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bio
nic_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета docker-scan-plugin.
Подготовка к распаковке …/5-docker-scan-plugin_0.8.0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается docker-scan-plugin (0.8.0~ubuntu-bionic) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета liberror-perl.
Подготовка к распаковке …/6-liberror-perl_0.17029-1_all.deb …
Распаковывается liberror-perl (0.17029-1) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета git-man.
Подготовка к распаковке …/7-git-man_1%3a2.25.1-1ubuntu3.1_all.deb …
Распаковывается git-man (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.1) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета git.
Подготовка к распаковке …/8-git_1%3a2.25.1-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.1) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета slirp4netns.
Подготовка к распаковке …/9-slirp4netns_0.4.3-1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается slirp4netns (0.4.3-1) …
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-i7eupn/2-docker-ce-cli_5%3a20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd6
4.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please ask and provide output in English - I suspect the amount of people who can help you in Russian is severely limited.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you mix focal (20.04 LTS) and bionic (18.04 LTS)?

Comment: Please include the output of `grep -ir "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list`, `apt-cache policy docker-ce-cli docker-ce` to the question. Which storage do you use? Are you sure it operates well? Your output has "<decompress> subprocess returned error" which may mean potential filesystem corruption. Have you tried to run `sudo apt-get clean` and retry?

Comment: I don't understand where bionic (18.04 LTS) comes from. Where do you see this? How can I fix this?

Comment: "Распаковывается docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) …" . And please answer the questions.